# What kind of relationship would be this many to many database structure?

Tags: mysql, database

When I have these tables:

```
Customer: Customer ID, Customer Name, Customer Surname
Product: Product ID, Product Name, Product Price
CustomerProduct: Customer ID, Product ID
```

I want to make a relationship diagram. I don't know How to set the 1... 0..m 1..m relations

I would say

```
Customer 1 ----- 0..m CustomerProduct
Product 1 ------ 0..m CustomerProduct
```

( by considering: Customer can have several products,
Product can have several customers)

right?

Comment: It depends on your requirements and constraints. Can costumer have more than one product? Can product be related to more than one customer?

Comment: Customer can have 0 or Many products
Product can have 0 or many customer

Answer (score 0):

```
Yes, it is a many to many relationship.

your data will look like:
CustomerProduct:
Customer ID     Product ID
1               1234
2               3344
1               3344
3               1111
3               1234
```

This is a many to many relationship.
You can refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/java.817/a81358/05_dev1.htm) for drawing relationship diagrams.

HTH!

Comment: and is my relationship diagram right? by considering, customer can have 0 or many products, and product can have 0 or many customer

Comment: you mean, (Entity)Customer--->(Many)(Relation)CustomerProduct(Many)<---(Entity)Product.. right? if yes.. it is correct!

Comment: Customer 1 ----- 0..m CustomerProduct
Product 1 ------ 0..m CustomerProduct

I mean that :)